# Left Join Query gives a different result on deployment MySQL server compared to my development instancce. Why is this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a different result to a identical query on two different mysql 
servers. Can anyone shed any light on this??

table "forum_important" is empty on both servers, so I was expecting the result to be NULL | NULL as the left join would be an empty result set, but on the deployment server, NULL | 1 is returned.

here are my tables....

```
CREATE TABLE `forum` (
  `ix` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inits` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `open` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `recipient` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ix`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB 

 CREATE TABLE `forum_important` (
  `important_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `op` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `important_id` (`important_id`),
  KEY `forum_important_index` (`op`),
  CONSTRAINT `forum_important_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`important_id`) REFERENCES `forum` (`ix`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Below is the startup information from the MySQL client in each case, to show server versioning.

**DEVELOPMENT SERVER**
This is the result set I am looking for....

```
neil@slim-silver ~ $ mysql -u academy -p openmolar
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.6.30-1 (Debian)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select ix, inits, recipient, important_id, is_important 
from forum left join 
(select important_id, True as is_important from forum_important 
where op="HW") as t1 on t1.important_id = ix;
+------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| ix   | inits | recipient | important_id | is_important |
+------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 6459 | EG    | NW        |         NULL |         NULL |
| 6567 | JS    | SYED      |         NULL |         NULL |
+------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from forum_important;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

**DEPLOYMENT SERVER**
The query here returns all results as "important" - why?

```
academy@academy:~$ mysql -p openmolar
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 128
Server version: 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select ix, inits, recipient, important_id, is_important 
from forum left join 
(select important_id, True as is_important from forum_important 
where op="HW") as t1 on t1.important_id = ix;
+------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| ix   | inits | recipient | important_id | is_important |
+------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 6459 | EG    | NW        |         NULL |            1 |
| 6567 | JS    | SYED      |         NULL |            1 |
+------+-------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from forum_important;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You are using a keyword, TRUE, as a column name. If you do a basic `SELECT true AS is_important;` You will notice you get 1. Escape the column name  TRUE using backtick(``) .

Comment: The simplest assumption is that the data is different on the two servers.  I would particularly look at the table `forum_important`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but that is not the case. As the code above shows, that table is empty on both servers.

Comment: Tom - i am not using True as a column name. I am assigning a value of True to the virtual column "is_important".

Comment: Is it possible that you have `is_important` column in the `forum` table on the second server?

Comment: can you show us the data in each of your tables for both dev and deployment?

Comment: valex - no, the deployment schema is identical to the development schema.

Comment: Takarii the data is sensitive I am afraid, I have given a simplified schema which duplicates the problem.

Comment: btw in the future, don't use `describe` . Use `show create table myTableName`

Comment: Seems to be some side effect of MySQL 5.7 subquery optimizations.

Comment: Good point Drew, edited now.

Comment: Assuming data is the same, I don't expect this to work but try switching to a right join and order of tables. This is odd behavior so trying odd things... `select ix, inits, recipient, important_id, is_important 
from (select important_id, True as is_important from forum_important 
where op="HW") t1 right join forum on t1.important_id = ix;`

Comment: xQbert - that works a dream on both server variants. thanks!

Comment: OK, building on xQbert's right join answer, I have noticed further strange behaviour on MySQL 5.7 which is only introduced by ordering the result set! see this for information - http://paste.debian.net/820916/